# Style of froala for angular wrong

Tags: angular, froala

[I install and use froala， but only got this? what's wrong with it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M46O8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem upon first installing froala with angular. The problem is that in the index.html file in your src folder you probably have a line like below if you followed the installation instructions.

```
 <!-- index.html -->
 <link href="node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What is happening is that the link is not finding your froala_editor.pkgd.min.css package in your NPM. Check your paths.

The easiest way to fix is to just reference the file from a CDN and replace with the link below.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.2/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```